# Firebase calling .remove() on ref is removing all parents

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the following code, after processing the data returned in the snapshot, I am seeking to remove the record in question. When I call remove on my reference with the key of the record appended via the child method all of the parent nodes are removed up to the root of the FB app. I suspect it is an error in my code. Would appreciate any assistance that can be provided.

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var config = require('./config.json');
var fbRef = new Firebase(config.firebaseEndpoint + "/messages");
var messenger = require('./messenger.js');

fbRef.on('value', function (snap) {

//If Data is returned convert payload to array.
//pass each mesaage into messenger and upon completion delete the
// firebase record
if (snap.exists()) {

    var payload = snap.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(payload);

    keys.forEach(function (key) {

        var msg = payload[key];

        messenger(msg, function (msgErr, msgData) {
            if (!msgErr) {

                fbRef.child(key).remove();
            }
            else {
                console.log(msgErr);
            }
        });
     });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without seeing your JSON structure (hint: add it to your question as text), but I think you may be mistaking how Firebase operates.

Firebase stores values at locations identified by paths. When you store a value at a location, the path is automatically created. When you remove the last value from a location, the path is automatically removed.

Aside from that, this code is somewhat more idiomatic:

```
fbRef.on('value', function (snap) {
  if (snap.exists()) {
    snap.forEach(function(msgSnap) {          
      var msg = msgSnap.val();
      messenger(msg, function (msgErr, msgData) {
        if (!msgErr) {
          msgSnap.ref().remove();
        }
        else {
          console.log(msgErr);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Frank thanks for this. You identified the gap in my knowledge as I didn't realize that the path is removed along with the last child. Also, thanks for pointing out the forEach on the snap. I missed that in the API and it will save me some time moving forward.