# Firebase removeValue removes parent instead of single value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to remove a simple value on my firebase tree like this:

[image: example]

To do that, I need to get the current userId, the name of the clicked group and the user that was clicked. I get all that information, and then I do this to delete:

```
id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
group = getIntent().getStringExtra("group");
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference().child("Users");
     builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            myRef.child(id).child("FriendLists").child(group).child(user.getId()).removeValue();
                            usersList.remove(user);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
```

The thing is, removeValue deletes all the node beginning at FriendLists, all the info and even the FriendLists dissapaear :S, any info, any help?

Comment: where does `myRef` refer to? and try to print all refs to ensure you're getting the correct route like printing `group` and `user.getId()`

Comment: i think instead of removing the value you can set it to null

Comment: edited the question, is it because i am using myRef in other sides of my code? do i need to create a new 1 to delete?

Comment: if you remove that value **grupo1** will remove automatically.

Comment: No that cant be the reason.Check that there are no null values.

Comment: exactly, what can be the cause?

Comment: and when i try to remove after adding the app crashes, when it reinitialize it works, another strange issue

Comment: tried to set the value to null, same behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Firebase automatically creates a path when you store a value at that path. It also removes a path if there is no longer any value under that path. So when you remove the last friend from a group, the group will also disappear. And then it's the last group, then the `FriendsList` parent also disappears.

Also see:

- [Firebase calling .remove() on ref is removing all parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440315/firebase-calling-remove-on-ref-is-removing-all-parents)